# Bootstrap button dropdown with custom content

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'd like to use Bootstrap's [button dropdown](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns) to display a form component instead of a list of other buttons with additional information. Is it possible?

Comment: show some image regading your question

Comment: why did this get closed? this question is quite clear. Maybe revoke moderation rights from the moderators

Answer (score 15):

Yes, this is possible by replacing the usual `<li><a>text</a></li>` that is inside the button dropdown with `<li>[form code] </li>`; I have added a form into a dropdown like so;

**Code:**

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Click for form <span class="caret"></span>

    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li>
          <div class="container">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label label-default="" for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1"
                placeholder="Enter email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label label-default="" for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1"
                placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label label-default="" for="exampleInputFile">File input</label>
                <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile">
                <p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox">Check me out</label>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Preview:**

[image: bootstrap button drop down with form]

[DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/GGYuvQm0MS)

Comment: you should add prevent close event in the li.

Comment: It will be much better with `container-fluid` instead, form should not become all screen wide.

Comment: there are still a lot to do, if you go this way. each click on form elements will hide the dropdown because it assumes you made a selection of the list. Using a popover with some modification makes more sense than hacking a list item.

Comment: @guyfawkes , as has already been commented it would need a prevent close. Feel free to submit an edit to improve this answer.

Comment: @Jordan.J.D the easiest way I can think of is adding an event handler to it to keep it open.
`$(function(){
 $('.dropdown-menu :input').on('focus click blur' , function(e){
     e.stopPropagation();
 })
})`